# How can I populate a TableView in JavaFX by using Arraylist?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to populate table view in javafx by using array list .I do not want to use any model .i want to make array list as my source of data for populating tableview .

```
Code:


List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
    doubles.add(12.12d);
    ObservableList<Double> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(doubles);

    TableView table_view = new TableView<>(names);

    firstDataColumn.setCellFactory(?????);/// here the problem comes what is the cell factory in case of arraylist
```

Comment: Do you have some code that you actually have tried and not succeeded?

Comment: I have tried with hashmap but i couldnot do it.And i am a swt programmer all these javafx stuff is alien to me

Comment: did you put it inside a ObservableList?

Comment: OP asked how to populate a TableView, why are the answers talking about ListView?

Answer (score 2):

You must use a `ObservableList` as your datasource and to achieve this when you have a `List` you can use:

```
FXCollections.observableList(yourList);
```

Comment: but what about cell factory...plz check my new edited question

Answer (score 1):

If there is no model then you want to show only one column list. So after taking assumption of that your arraylist's object type is the wrapper class (of the primitive data types) like Integer, Double, String etc., you can use [ListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) instead of TableView.

```
List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
doubles.add(12.12d);
ObservableList<Double> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(doubles);
ListView<Double> listView = new ListView<Double>(names);
```

Comment: i donot want to use listview as i have multiple columns .. But i donot want to use any model as no of columns depending on the items on the list i have edited the question please check.

Comment: @Rajesh. Just use dummy model and get rid of all low level API complexities. Or use multiple listviews.